# How can I change Section 1.1 to Section 1.A

Tags: sectioning

Due to COVID-19, we have to answer examinations online. We are given an examination paper and are answering it accordingly on our own.

The question paper comes in the format `Question 3.A, Question 3.B` etc.

I was wondering if there was a way to change the Latex section referencing format to appear like this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try this!

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}} % 

\section{Title}

\subsection{Subtitle}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsection}} % 

\subsection{Subtitle}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}} % 
\subsection{Subtitle}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\roman{subsection}} % 
\subsection{Subtitle}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}} % 
\subsection{Subtitle}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what was looking for! And if I wanted to remove the capitlisation of the letter?

Comment: see all options now!! =)